# psycopg2 not actually inserting data

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to insert JSON data from tornado to postgres, so here's test like this:

```
from psycopg2 import connect

conn = connect("user='pguser' host='localhost' dbname='pgdb' password='pgpass'")
cursor = conn.cursor()

data = '[{"id":"sdf","name":"wqe","author":"vb"}]'

for row in eval(data):
  print row
  cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO books(id,name,author) VALUES('%s','%s','%s')""" % \
        (row['id'], row['name'], row['author'])
  )

>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
>>> cursor.fetchall()
[('sdf', 'wqe', 'vb')]
>>> 
$> psql -d pgdb -U pguser -W
Password for user pguser: 
psql (9.1.6)
Type "help" for help.

pgdb=> select * from books;
 id | name | author 
----+------+--------
(0 rows)
```

As you can see after doing `select` in python shell, there's some data, but in psql there's
0 rows! What may I be doing wrong?

Python 2.7.2+

Comment: granting GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE pgdb to pguser; and changing peer to trust in hba.conf didn't help

Comment: Both of those are attempts to solve a problem you don't have. You'd be getting permissions errors if either of those were issues.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You didn't commit the transaction.

Psycopg2 opens a transaction automatically, and you must tell it to commit in order to make the data visible to other sessions.

See [the psycopg2 FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html) and the [`connection.commit()` method](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit).

Comment: Some answers are worth 100 up votes - even after 4 years. This is one of them! :)

Comment: @rjurney Please submit a pull request to the psycopg2 repository to add it then :) at the most logical place you'd expect to find it in the docs.

Comment: For other people worried they may keep forgetting this step: it may also be of use to set `autocommit` to `True` for the session: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.set_session

Comment: The faq should also remind the difference between using the connection within a with() statement or a cursor... :(

Comment: Re: `with()` statement: a `commit()` is automatically performed at the end of a `with` block assuming no errors occurred. Note that the connection remains open. For those who found themselves here and didn't know. :)

Comment: When you have a SELECT statement you don't need `commit()`, at least in my case

Comment: @CarMoreno If the `SELECT` was read-only and didn't call any data-modifying functions or views, that is correct. It's a good habit anyway though.

Comment: @CraigRinger You're saying the commit is only necessary to make it visible to **other** sessions. Does this mean that if I do an update followed by a select on the updated data on the **same** session, the updated data will be found without having to make a commit in between the update and select?

Comment: @Philipp Yes. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html . That's necessary for most transactions to make any sense; otherwise running `BEGIN; UPDATE t SET x = x + 1; UPDATE t SET x = x - 1; COMMIT;` would cause all `x` values to go down by 1, since the second update wouldn't see the changes made by the first in the same txn.

Comment: @Philipp There are various complexities around the rules for when new changes become visible in the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation, mostly relating to multi-part (compound) statements, statements that call functions, etc. But for most simple purposes you can assume your statement will "see" changes committed by other txns before your statement started, *and* changes made by prior statements in the same txn.

Comment: @Philipp There are other isolation modes like `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE` that have different rules and behaviour. It's worth understanding these, but for most applications the default isolation level `READ COMMITTED` is what you will want most of the time.

Answer (score 8):

Just had the same perplexing issue. To put options together:

as @Craig Ringer writes after cursor.execute you can run connection.commit

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES(DEFAULT, %s)', email)
...
connection.commit()
```

OR
after connect set autocommit

```
connection = connect("user='pguser' host='localhost' dbname='pgdb' password='pgpass'")
connection.autocommit = True
```

OR
use set_session to set autocommit

```
connection = connect("user='pguser' host='localhost' dbname='pgdb' password='pgpass'") 
connection.set_session(autocommit=True)
```

All worked for me.