# Python psycopg2 pool connection timeout

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I have the following class that I am using to pool connections for my application.

```
import os
import psycopg2
import contextlib
from psycopg2 import pool
from contextlib import contextmanager

class DbHandler:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.reconnect_pool()


    def reconnect_pool(self):
        self.pgPool = psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 128, user=os.getenv("PGUSER"), password=os.getenv("PGPASSWORD"), host=os.getenv("PGHOST"), port=os.getenv("PGPORT"), database=os.getenv("PGDATABASE"))
        
    # Get Cursor
    @contextmanager
    def get_cursor(self):
        if(self.pgPool):
            conn = self.pgPool.getconn()
            if(conn):
                try:
                    yield conn.cursor()
                    conn.commit()
                finally:
                    self.pgPool.putconn(conn)
        else:
            self.reconnect_pool() 


     # Get Cursor
    @contextmanager
    def get_connection(self):
        if(self.pgPool):
            conn = self.pgPool.getconn()
            if(conn):
                try:
                    yield conn
                finally:
                    self.pgPool.putconn(conn)
        else:
            self.reconnect_pool() 


    # Helper function
    def getRows(self, cursor):
        rows=[]
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row is not None:
            rows.append(row)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
        return rows


    def getPoolSize(self):
        if(self.pgPool):
            return len(self.pgPool._used)
        else:
            return -1
```

I am executing the code in the following manner inside my code by instantiating and calling the cursor.

```
 def Login(self,username,password):
        with self.db.get_cursor() as psCursor:
            psCursor.execute("select users.username, users.id, string_agg(coalesce(keys.service, ''), ',') from users left join keys on keys.user_id = users.id where users.username = '" + username + "' and users.password='" + password + "'" + "group by (users.username,users.id)")
            rows = self.db.getRows(psCursor)                    
            if len(rows) == 0:
                return None
            if len(rows) > 0:
                return rows[0]
```

But once i stop using the application for a while and try to execute any sql query. I get the error below

```
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074414377Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 284, in handle
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074428178Z     keepalive = self.handle_request(req, conn)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074432778Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 333, in handle_request
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074438078Z     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074442378Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074446678Z     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074450879Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074455079Z     response = self.handle_exception(e)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074459279Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074463479Z     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074467779Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074472080Z     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074476280Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074480580Z     raise value
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074484580Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074488780Z     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074492880Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074497181Z     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074501181Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074505381Z     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074509581Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074513781Z     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074520082Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074524382Z     raise value
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074528382Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074532682Z     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074536682Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074541083Z     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074545183Z   File "/whaii/routes/index.py", line 126, in login
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074549383Z     user = MatchFunc.Login(str(data.get('username')),str(data.get('password')))
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074556783Z   File "/whaii/routes/Whaii_Engine.py", line 148, in Login
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074562384Z     psCursor.execute("select users.username, users.id, string_agg(coalesce(keys.service, ''), ',') from users left join keys on keys.user_id = users.id where users.username = '" + username + "' and users.password='" + password + "'" + "group by (users.username,users.id)")
2020-09-01T07:11:05.074567584Z psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out
```

I am guessing it is the way I am calling the cursor. It would be great if someone could point out how I can reuse the connection pool.
Also, I ran `SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity;` and I can see that there are about 26 connections that are active but I am confused as to why the query fails.

Comment: You are not committing the transaction after the execute command, so the connection stay in idle state and run into timeout. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13715838/5532710)

Comment: mate now it makes total sense now. Thanks so much.

Comment: @CarloZanocco -- could you make that an answer?